# Error while compile CSS file into SWF through command line

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5

I compile my CSS file through command line then i got error like

```
C:\Users\Raykor\Desktop\css>mxmlc myCss.css
'mxmlc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Can anyone please help me to compile CSS file through command line.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add "mxmlc.exe" path in environment variables.